# Can I freeze pasta sauce which is made with fresh cream?

Tags: food-safety

Im making pasta sauce with fresh cream. Is it safe to deep freeze the sauce in a tupperware container for later use.

Comment: Why not? What is special about fresh cream?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to freeze cream-based sauces, provided you thoroughly reheat it before consuming. The sauce might be a little less appealing than when freshly made, but it won't harm you.

As a side note, I would definitely recommend only freezing the sauce, and cooking pasta 'to order' (if you were not planning on this already). Cooked, frozen, then reheated pasta is very difficult not to overcook.